# Ng Model Options is not working from $scope variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

My `ng-model` should update 
  Onblur: Immediately
  Typing: after 0.5 sec. Why is this not happening?

```js
app = angular.module("dailySheetApp", []);
app.controller("dailySheetCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.inputBounce= { "updateOn":"default blur","debounce":{"default":500,"blur":0} };


});
```

```html
<html ng-app="dailySheetApp">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-controller="dailySheetCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data" ng-model="inputBounce">
  {{data}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of things are not quite correct here. Firstly, you did not declare `ng-model-options` correctly. Observe the markup change. Secondly, [ngModelOptions](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) is not available in 1.2.x. The updated example is using 1.3.0

```js
app = angular.module("dailySheetApp", []);
app.controller("dailySheetCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.inputBounce= { "updateOn":"default blur","debounce":{"default":500,"blur":0} };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="dailySheetApp">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <body ng-controller="dailySheetCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data" ng-model-options="inputBounce">
    {{data}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is working here but in application it is not working., what you have changed actually ...

Comment: I changed the markup, as indicated. `ng-model-options="inputBounce"`. You can **not** use v1.2.x of AngularJS, it was not implemented yet. You need to use at least 1.3.0. The example I have provided is using version 1.3.0

Comment: @ManikantaReddy If you are committed to using AngularJS 1.2.x, you can always write a custom directive that will debouce the model (or only set it on blur). I know for a fact there are some open-source solutions.

Comment: What @CalebWilliams is saying is a possibility. Hopefully you can upgrade, but these are the main reasons your example is not working in your original question.